# Service to upload images to multiple social networks from button on website

Tags: facebook-graph-api, twitter, social-networking, html5-canvas

I am working on a html5 canvas art tool ( http://bit.ly/AtFoRQ ) and I would really like to find a drop-in solution to allow users to share the image they have just created with their facebook, flicker, twitpic, in one shot; does anyone know of a service like this?

Basically I'm looking for something almost exactly like addThis, but that actually uploads image data (so in facebook it would upload photo to the users album, etc).  shareKit for iPhone apps actually does this (the uploading of the raw image data through the apis), but unfortunately there doesn't exist a version of it for websites.

I know that I can hand code all of the connections to each social network myself, but seeing services like addThis and shareKit leads me to believe that there must be a service out there that already does what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These services provide REST targets, there is no need to use a third party. If you want to enable login from your site you should look into [openID](http://openid.net/).

Once the client is validated you can route their canvas image to the service. 
see: [facebook photos.upload](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload/)